# Why does the last KB of a PDF take so long to load?

Tags: windows, pdf, internet-explorer, pdf-reader

I'm loading a 357 KB PDF, and the first 356 KBs loaded almost instantly, whereas the last KB is taking forever to load.

I encounter this problem as I load PDFs in varying sizes from varied sources.

Why does this happen, and more importantly, how can I fix it?

Comment: Which PDF reader's ActiveX plugin are you using in IE? Have you tried a different PDF reader?

Comment: @Karan I'm not an administrator, so I can't try using a different reader.  How do I check which ActiveX plugin I'm using?

Comment: In IE go to `Toola / Manage add-ons` and check the list of installed Extensions. Also, are you facing the same slow loading problem if you save the PDFs locally and then launch them directly in your PDF reader?

Comment: What do you mean "last KiB takes forever to load"? If the PDF file isn't present entirely, it is missing pieces that are vital for displaying it.

Comment: @vonbrand I mean that it has loaded 99.9%, and for some reason, the last .1% takes longer than the 99.9% did.

Comment: @Karan No I don't face that same problem.  So it must be the reader.  I'll talk to the admin, thanks.  If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Standard Windows trick? The first 80% zip by, the last 20% take forever.

Comment: The first 99% is probably just downloading the file. The last 1% is initializing the plugin, rendering the content, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're sure it's not a network issue (delay while downloading the last bit of the file), and if you don't face a problem loading the PDF after saving it locally, might be an issue with the reader's ActiveX plugin for IE. Ask the system admin to look into this.